# Ruby hash returning strange values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am returning a response of user fields in JSON. I am creating JSON as below.

```
def user_response(users)
    users_array = []
    users.each do |user|
      uhash = {}
      uhash[:id] = user.id,
      uhash[:nickname] = user.nickname,
      uhash[:online_sharing] = user.online_sharing,
      uhash[:offline_export] = user.offline_export,
      uhash[:created_at] = user.created_at,
      uhash[:app_opens_count] = user.app_opens_count,
      uhash[:last_activity] = user.last_activity,
      uhash[:activity_goal] = user.activity_goal,
      uhash[:last_activity] = user.last_activity,
      uhash[:region] = user.region
      users_array << uhash
    end
    users_array
  end
```

But the response is pretty weird. The `:id` key in hash has an array of all the fields don't know why.

```
{
    "nickname": "adidas",
    "online_sharing": null,
    "offline_export": null,
    "created_at": "2016-08-26T09:03:54.000Z",
    "app_opens_count": 29,
    "last_activity": "2016-08-26T09:13:01.000Z",
    "activity_goal": 3,
    "region": "US",
    "id": [
      9635,
      "adidas",
      null,
      null,
      "2016-08-26T09:03:54.000Z",
      29,
      "2016-08-26T09:13:01.000Z",
      3,
      "2016-08-26T09:13:01.000Z",
      "US"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Error is mentioned in below , but it is not  right way to write this method

Comment: The problem is explained below, but if it's not clear why the value of `uhash[:id]` is an array, if `uhash = {}; uhash[:id] = 1,2,3; uhash #=> {:id=>[1, 2, 3]} `. Having `1,`, `2,` and `3` on separate lines makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have comma `,` at the end of each line

> ```
> uhash[:id] = user.id,
> ```

Also, You may change the above code to:

```
def user_response(users)
  users.map do |user| 
    user.attributes.slice(:id, :nickname, :online_sharing, :offline_export, :created_at, :app_opens_count, :last_activity, :activity_goal, :last_activity, :region)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

That's due to your `,` at the end of each line

Answer (score 3):

The problem consists of two things:

1. An assignment evaluates as the value being assigned:

   ```
   puts (foo = 42) # => prints 42
   ```
2. Multiple values, separated with comma on the right hand side of an assignment form an array:

   ```
   bar = 1, 2, 3
   bar # => [1, 2, 3]
   ```

The new lines don't change that, so you basically do something like this:

```
sonne = (foo = :eins), (bar = :zwei), (baz = :drei), (qux = :vier)
sonne # => [:eins, :zwei, :drei, :vier]
```

The fix is indeed to remove the commas.

Comment: Users here tend to prefer instant solutions of their problem, rather than understand the problem by means of a decent explanation. This question serves a good example of this phenomenon. Very good answer! +1

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, To be fair, maybe it's not that black and white. Fallenhero's answer got the most upvotes because it was first and it's correctness can be instantly verified by anyone that understands the issue. My answer takes more time to read hence less likely to be verified and upvoted. Deepak's answer got accepted probably because OP learned something new and got an elegant implementation (as opposed to my answer that just teaches you something).

Comment: An ideal answer to this question should be one with a **tl;dr** heading (Fallenhero's answer) *-hr-* the actual explanation (my answer) *-hr-* a more idiomatic solution to the problem (Deepak's answer).

Comment: agree about things not being black and white, but at the end of the day, answer should aim to help (which I myself sometimes can forget), and yours looks to be the only one written with such goal :)